# log level in in unit tests of Neo4j

Tags: unit-testing, neo4j

I am unit testing an extension for Neo4j 3.0.x using the [official documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/java-reference/current/#server-extending). In each of my resources, I inject both the **GraphDatabaseService** and **org.neo4j.logging.Log** objects provided by Neo4j.

How can I configure the logger to print all DEBUG logs to stdout during my unit tests?

Actually, I couldn't even change the log level on a running instance of Neo4j either, regardless of the value I set in neo4j.conf: `dbms.logs.debug.level=DEBUG`

Comment: Did you figure this out in the end? I tried config.withLogging(new ConsoleLogging(Level.INFO)) but see dont see the logs

Comment: no, nothing. It's really annoying. I have to debug code in order to get the information I need.